# Allatori Obfuscator error compile runnable method (Java)

Tags: java, allatori

I use Allatori obfuscator ( http://www.allatori.com/ ). But If I have a runnable method, I have compilation error ( I see this in the java decompiler ).

```
new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
// TEST

   }

}
```

In java decompiler I have :

```
// This method could not be decompiled.
[...]
// The error that occurred was:
        //
        // java.lang.NullPointerException
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.convertType(AstBuilder.java:344)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.convertType(AstBuilder.java:173)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformCall(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:1119)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformByteCode(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:1009)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformExpression(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:540)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformByteCode(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:554)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformExpression(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:540)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformNode(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:392)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.transformBlock(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:333)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.createMethodBody(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:294)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstMethodBodyBuilder.createMethodBody(AstMethodBodyBuilder.java:99)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.createMethodBody(AstBuilder.java:782)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.createMethod(AstBuilder.java:675)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.addTypeMembers(AstBuilder.java:552)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.createTypeCore(AstBuilder.java:519)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.createTypeNoCache(AstBuilder.java:161)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.createType(AstBuilder.java:150)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.ast.AstBuilder.addType(AstBuilder.java:125)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.JavaLanguage.buildAst(JavaLanguage.java:71)
        //     at com.strobel.decompiler.languages.java.JavaLanguage.decompileType(JavaLanguage.java:59)
        //     at us.deathmarine.luyten.DecompilerLinkProvider.generateContent(DecompilerLinkProvider.java:97)
        //     at us.deathmarine.luyten.OpenFile.decompileWithNavigationLinks(OpenFile.java:494)
        //     at us.deathmarine.luyten.OpenFile.decompile(OpenFile.java:467)
        //     at us.deathmarine.luyten.Model.extractClassToTextPane(Model.java:420)
        //     at us.deathmarine.luyten.Model.openEntryByTreePath(Model.java:339)
        //     at us.deathmarine.luyten.Model$TreeListener$1.run(Model.java:266)
        //
        throw new IllegalStateException("An error occurred while decompiling this method.");
```

Have you a idea for fix that ? It's maybe that I need a lib of java ?

Comment: You talk about an obfuscator, but the exception stack trace is from a decompiler. So what exactly are you trying to do? If you obfuscate your own code, why would you need to decompile it afterwards? And if the decompiler can't handle the obfuscated code, that's surely a *good* thing, isn't it?

Comment: I have decompile the jar file because, when I lanch the file I have an other error : Malformed Class Name